# Why can Object.equals compare types that cannot be compared with the reference equality operator (==)?

Tags: java, object, equals, equality

I know in Java you can't compare two unrelated instances using `==`, since it produces a compilation error (incompatible types). So for example

```
class Animal {}
class Dog extends Animal {}
class Cat extends Animal {}

Dog d = new Dog();
Cat c = new Cat();
System.out.println( d == c );
```

is a compile-time error.

But why doesn't using equals inherited from `Object` produce that kind of error:

```
System.out.println( d.equals(c) );  // is false
```

even though `Object.equals` internally uses `==`?

Now, I know why it's `false`, but I don't know why it's not an error, since the signature is:

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    return (this == obj);
}
```

Comment: Because in `Object#equals` the types you compare are both `Object`?

Comment: @GaëlJ: i think you're damn right. i tested:
` Object od = d;   
  Object oc = c;
  System.out.println( od == oc );` and it's false, not compile error, so your answer is correct.

Comment: The compiler doesn’t have to examine any code to know that an instance of Dog cannot be an instance of Cat, since neither class inherits from the other.  However, to determine whether calling `equals` is guaranteed to be false, the compiler would have to examine the logic of the `equals` method.  It is theoretically possible to provide the same compilation error if the types both inherit `equals` from java.lang.Object, but that special case probably isn’t worth the effort to implement in the compiler.

Answer (score 2):

Because inside `Object#equals` the types you compare are both `Object`, thus the `==` operator is "allowed".

*Remember though that you most of the time don't want to compare using `==` or the default `Object#equals` as it compares the references, not the content. See [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520432/what-is-the-difference-between-and-equals-in-java?r=SearchResults&s=3|156.7237](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520432/what-is-the-difference-between-and-equals-in-java?r=SearchResults&s=3%7C156.7237)*

Answer (score 0):

The compile time check is performed at the site of the reference equality — within `Object.equals`.  In the context of the `Object.equals` method you referenced, it is comparing `this` with an `Object`:

```java
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    return (this == obj);
}
```

Per the [Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.21.3):

> It is a compile-time error if it is impossible to convert the type of either operand to the type of the other by a casting conversion ([§5.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.5)). The run-time values of the two operands would necessarily be unequal (ignoring the case where both values are `null`).

Since `this` can be cast to `Object`, `this == obj` is a valid usage of the reference equality operator (`==`), and therefore it compiles.

---

For a practical example, observe a case within the Java API where two objects cannot be compared via reference equality (`==`), but which are equal when compared via `Object.equals`.

First, note that the implementation of `Object.equals` is just the *base* implementation of `equals`.  Subclasses of `Object` are encouraged to use a different implementation, if appropriate.

Second, note that unlike the reference equals operator (`==`), the [`equals`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) method has no restriction on whether two compared objects can be cast to the type of the other.  Per the [Javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) of `Object.equals`, the two objects need only implement an *equivalence relation*:

> The `equals` method implements an equivalence relation on non-null object references:
>
> - It is *reflexive*: for any non-null reference value `x`, `x.equals(x)` should return `true`.
> - It is *symmetric*: for any non-null reference values `x` and `y`, `x.equals(y)` should return `true` if and only if `y.equals(x)` returns `true`.
> - It is *transitive*: for any non-null reference values `x`, `y`, and `z`, if `x.equals(y)` returns `true` and `y.equals(z)` returns `true`, then `x.equals(z)` should return `true`.
> - It is *consistent*: for any non-null reference values `x` and `y`, multiple invocations of `x.equals(y)` consistently return `true` or consistently return `false`, provided no information used in `equals` comparisons on the objects is modified.
> - For any non-null reference value `x`, `x.equals(null)` should return `false`.

Take the Java [`List`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html) interface.  It specifies how implementing classes must implement equals:

> Compares the specified object with this list for equality. Returns `true` if and only if the specified object is also a list, both lists have the same size, and all corresponding pairs of elements in the two lists are *equal*. (Two elements `e1` and `e2` are *equal* if `Objects.equals(e1, e2)`.) In other words, two lists are defined to be equal if they contain the same elements in the same order. This definition ensures that the equals method works properly across different implementations of the `List` interface.

Now, take two lists that can't be cast to one another, such as [`ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ArrayList.html) and [`LinkedList`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/LinkedList.html).  A `LinkedList` reference cannot be compared with an `ArrayList` reference using the reference equality error (`==`), since neither type can be cast to the other.  On the other hand, an `ArrayList` will be `.equals` to a `LinkedList` if they contain the same elements in the same order.

```java
ArrayList<String> a = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("X", "Y", "Z"));
LinkedList<String> b = new LinkedList<String>(Arrays.asList("X", "Y", "Z"));

assert a.equals(b); // true
assert a == b; // compiler error
```